# changing value of variable on another scope with method in C#

Tags: c#, ref, out

I have came across strange method called "Recieve()" in .NET.Sockets
.Recieve() method changes buff variable without using ref or out. Can somebody explain to me pls.

Full Code:

```
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Any;

        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 23000);

        server.Bind(endPoint);

        server.Listen(5);

        Socket client = server.Accept();

        Console.WriteLine("Client endpoint : " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        byte[] buff = new byte[128];

        //this method confuses me Receive(buff)
        int numberOfRecievedBytes = client.Receive(buff);

        Console.WriteLine("Number of Recieved Bytes: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff, 0, numberOfRecievedBytes));
```

Comment: `byte[]` is a reference type. Any method can modify the contents of an array passed as a parameter (they cannot modify the reference in `buff` itself without `ref` or `out`, but that's a different thing).

Comment: This behavior is described in the C# programming guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/passing-arrays-as-arguments). (Oddly enough, the guide does not see fit to describe in the dedicated topics for reference types and arrays that arrays are reference types, even though that's an important thing to know.)

Comment: Shoot! you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Byte[] is a reference type; you are passing a reference to an array of type byte.
You can mutate its contents, but not the reference itself.